# Is there a way to perform calculations of Mandelbrot set using only integer numbers?

Tags: computational-geometry

I would like to create program in JavaScript (JS) which draws [Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) with arbitrary precision (zoom). In JS there is build in integer type [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) which support simple operations like +,*,/,power on arbitrary precision integer numbers. JS not support calculations on arbitrary precision floating point numbers.

**Question**: Is there a way to perform calculations of Mandelbrot set using calculations based only on integers (with arbitrary precision) - if yes how to do it?

Comment: Did you try to model your arithmetic after floats? That is, represent every number as a pair of signed BigInts $(m,e)$, which denotes number $m \times 2^e$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Computer_drawings, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Perturbation_theory_and_series_approximation